# How to reverse a table to string again?

Tags: arrays, lua

I'm working with tables and i wanted to convert a table to string again.
First i did this:

```
local function TableToString(t)
return "{"..table.concat(t,",").."}"
end

local MyTable = {4,5,21,7}
print(TableToString(MyTable))--It prints {4,5,21,7}
```

But then i tried with a table with keys and values:

```
local MyTable2 = {Key1=5819,Key2=28194,Key3=1888}
print(TableToString(MyTable2))--It prints " "
```

So i did this:

```
local function TableToString(t)
if #t == 0 then
TempTab={}
for i,v in next,t do
table.insert(TempTab,i.."="..v)
end
t=TempTab
end
return "{"..table.concat(t,",").."}"
end

local MyTable = {4,5,21,7}
local MyTable2 = {Key1=5819,Key2=28194,Key3=1888}

print(TableToString(MyTable)
)--It prints {4,5,21,7}
print(TableToString(MyTable2))--It prints {Key1=5819,Key2=28194,Key3=1888}
```

But then, an array of arrays

```
local MyTable3 = {Key1={Subkey1={}},Key2={Subkey2={}},Key3={Subkey3={}}}
print(TableToString(MyTable3))--[Error]attempt to concatenate local 'v' (a table value)
```

Now i don't know what to do.
**FIXED**

```lua
local Is=setmetatable({},{
  __index=function(t,k)
  compare = function(to)
  if type(to):lower() == k:lower() then
  return true
  end
  return false
  end
  if k:lower() == "matrix" then
  compare = function (to)
  if type(to) == "table" and #to == 0 then
  return true
  end
  return false
  end
  end
  return compare
  end
})

function TTS(t)
if Is.Table(t) then
local TempTab={}
if not Is.matrix(t) then
return "{"..table.concat(t,",").."}"
else
for i,v in pairs(t) do
if not Is.Table(v) then
table.insert(TempTab,i.."="..v)
else
table.insert(TempTab,i.."="..TTS(v))
end
end
return "{"..table.concat(TempTab,",").."}"
end
end
end
local MyTable3 = {Key1={Subkey1={}},Key2={Subkey2={}},Key3={Subkey3={}}}
print(TableToString(MyTable3))--Prints {Key1={Subkey1={}},Key2={Subkey2={}},Key3={Subkey3={}}}
```

There's the function is someone wants to use it ;)

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/12.1.html

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  Nvm, i fixed it.